# Is it possible to not yield from a certain page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Trying to have a page which will not take everything from layouts/application.html.erb, Is it possible?

Comment: Can you post an example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Just trying to make my form in a controller not take anything from layouts/application

Comment: Which version of rails are you using? `render :layout => false` works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller:

```
def my_action
  render :layout => false
end
```

Comment: Nothing actually renders if i add that

Comment: Is your view in `app/views/my_controller/my_action.html.erb`?

Answer (score 2):

The following will display your content unless you are on a specific page:

```
yield(:something) unless controller_name == 'mycontroller' and action_name == 'myaction'
```

The following will output header and includes unless you are on a specific page:

```
if controller_name == 'mycontroller' and action_name == 'myaction'
  javascript_include_tag :defaults
  javascript_include_tag 'anotherscript.js'
  yield(:head)
end
```

Comment: That removes the text im trying to remove the header and includes which are in layouts/application

Comment: I edited my answer. Is it what you are looking for? If not, you may want to use a dedicated layout for your particular action.

Comment: Im looking to not render the application.html.erb basically something like render :layout => false which doesnt actually work

Comment: controller_name still helpful for me in rails 7 :D thx

Answer (score 1):

Calling `render :action => "foo", :layout => false` in your controller will skip your layout entirely.